# Vendor ID uniqueness among different devices for same application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uuid

I have been using the `identifierForVendor` for creating unique identifier for my application. As per the document in :

[identifierForVendor](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor)

It states that

```
"The value of this property is the same for apps that come from the same vendor running on the same device. A different value is returned for apps on the same device that come from different vendors, and for apps on different devices regardless of vendor.

Normally, the vendor is determined by data provided by the App Store. If the app was not installed from the app store (such as enterprise apps and apps still in development), then a vendor identifier is calculated based on the app’s bundle ID. The bundle ID is assumed to be in reverse-DNS format."
```

This is the code in objective C

```
 NSString *UDIDString = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
    NSLog(@"Vendor ID %@", UDIDString);
```

Below are my queries

A) Will the vendor ID for my application named "App_A" return the same vendor ID for different devices if installed from App Store? Or each device will have different vendorID for same application which is installed from AppStore?

B) Are there any chances of vendorID getting changed if i update the application with new version?

Any inputs is appreciated . Please help with the queries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Unique ID per device.
2. No, the Vendor ID will not change with version updates.

---

**Edit**

From Apple's docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620059-identifierforvendor):

> The value in this property remains the same while the app (or another app from the same vendor) is installed on the iOS device. ***The value changes when the user deletes all of that vendor’s apps from the device and subsequently reinstalls one or more of them***. The value can also change when installing test builds using Xcode ***or when installing an app on a device using ad-hoc distribution***. Therefore, if your app stores the value of this property anywhere, you should gracefully handle situations where the identifier changes.

That seems to pretty clearly answer your questions.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation
One more Query 
A) If in case i install the same application with same bundle id using Developer certificate or Ad Hoc certificate in different devices. Will they be same or unique for each device?

Comment: Couldn't tell you (without testing it, which you can do yourself) how the VendorID is generated with Ad Hoc distribution. But, if it's installed from the AppStore - even if it has the same bundle ID and Dev / Dist certificate(s), it will **not** get the same VendorID on two different devices.

Comment: Thanks again.
Is there any chance that VendorID will change if i uninstall and install application from AppStore?

Comment: @Fionashoff - see the edit to my answer... should be clear.

Comment: Thanks :) Please calrify "The value can also change when installing test builds using Xcode or when installing an app on a device using ad-hoc distribution"  Is this not a sure thing like may or may not change? Because right now my team found they were same for different devices for same application when installed through Ad Hoc certificate.

Comment: I don't work for Apple.. I'm just reading the docs. Note the wording *"**CAN** also change..."*. If you're trying to rely on it NOT changing, or being the same across devices regardless of distribution method, you're asking for trouble.